# Unit Testing Generic Unit of Work and Repository Pattern framework using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, moq, unit-of-work

I'm at my wits end. I'm learning how to use [the Generic Unit of Work and Repository pattern framework](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/) . I've got no problem setting up the controllers, unity, and views... they all work on live data. My issue is unit testing these async repositories.

I've came across numerous posts here in stackoverflow and articles in MSDN with regards to [mocking the DataContext using Moq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async).

However, upon executing the tests, I seem to be facing a roadblock and I have no idea how to fix this. Please bear with me.

Here is the controller I'm testing:

```
public class TeamsController : Controller
{
   private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _uow;
   private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Team> _repo;

   public TeamsController(IUnitOfWorkAsync uow)
   {
      _uow = uow;
      _repo = _uow.RepositoryAsync<Team>();
   }

   // GET: Teams
   public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
   {
      return View(await _repo.Queryable().ToListAsync());
   }
}
```

Here is the unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Index_AccessIndexPage_MustPass()
{
   // arrange
   var data = new List<Team> 
   { 
      new Team { Id = 1 }
   }.AsQueryable();

   Mock<DbSet<Team>> mockSet = data.GenerateMockDBSet<Team>();
   var mockContext = new Mock<IDataContextAsync>();
   mockContext.As<IDBContext>().Setup(c => c.Teams).Returns(mockSet.Object);

   _uow = new UnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);

   // act
   _controller = new TeamsController(_uow);
   var result = await _controller.Index();
   var model = (List<Team>)((ViewResult)result).Model;

   // assert
   Assert.IsNotNull(model);
   Assert.AreEqual(model.Count, 2);
}
```

Here is the utility I got from MSDN:

```
public static Mock<DbSet<TEnt>> GenerateMockDBSet<TEnt>(this IQueryable<TEnt> data)
            where TEnt : Entity
{
  var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEnt>>();
  mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEnt>>()
         .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
         .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<TEnt>(data.GetEnumerator()));

  mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEnt>>()
         .Setup(m => m.Provider)
         .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEnt>(data.Provider));

  mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEnt>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
  mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEnt>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
  mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEnt>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
  mockSet.As<IQueryable<TEnt>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator);

  return mockSet;
}
```

Here is the actual exception from the unit test:

```
Test method MyMVC.Tests.Controllers.TeamsControllerTest.Index_AccessIndexPage_MustPass threw exception: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

The exception is fired during the actual .Queryable() call because the IRepositoryAsync _repo seems to be throwing a null.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the code for your UnitOfWork? It's easier & more complete if we can see it here inline. Specifically, I want to see the constructor and RepositoryAsync calls, because you're passing the mockContext to the ouw's constructor. My guess is in your TeamsController ctor, `_uow.RepositoryAsync<Team>()` is calling something on your mockContext that you haven't setup yet, so that results in TeamsController._repo being null upon class instantiation.

Comment: Hi Damon, as I've mentioned. The code for UOW and Gen Repo is provided by an open source library. It's not necessarily null all through out, but only the part where I convert it to .Queryable(). Cheers!

Comment: Martin, I am running into this same error.  My code is not exactly the same as your code, but it is very similar.  Would you mind post an answer with what your code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller depend on IUnitOfWorkAsync, and that's what need to be mocked. You shouldn't be using a "real" new UnitOfWork.

I suggest that you create mocks for the async repository, etc.:

```
var myData = new List<Team>(); //fill whatever test data you need

var repo = new Mock<IRepositoryAsync<Team>>();
repo.Setup(r=>r.Queryable()).Returns(myData.AsQueryable());
var uow = new Mock<IUnitOfWorkAsync>();
uow.Setup(u=>u.RepositoryAsync<Team>()).Returns(repo.Object);
```

Comment: Cheers Sunny, I finally figured it out!: Instead of using the myData.AsQueryable() in the Returns, I applied this: repo.Setup(r => r.Queryable()).Returns(mockContext.As<IBugFixRocksContext>().Object.Teams.AsQueryable());

Comment: @MartinOngtangco: you can do it that way - but IMHO you go too deep. Why would you need to use yet another mock which you need to setup? Using a list is more natural, as you can prepare it much easier, and for various test and/remove items as you see fit. The mock will go in your way in the moment you decide to add some Where clause for example.

Comment: i got into an issue with the queryable list. This was the only solution. Thanks